# @Scheduled running at 16:00

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I've created this method in SpringBoot

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 16 * * * *")
    public void sendMsg() {
}
```

to be executed At 16:00 pm (noon) every day:

but instead is executed several times per day

Comment: //second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday  - here is explanation for every * in @Schedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed by previous answers your expression is not valid "Spring expression", but rather unix expression. Spring utilizes [Quartz-type](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) which adds a value of seconds as a very first parameter:

```
+-------------------- second (0 - 59)
|  +----------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  |  +-------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  |  +----------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  |  +-------- month (1 - 12)
|  |  |  |  |  +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
|  |  |  |  |  |  +-- year [optional]
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  *  *  * command to be executed
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38631616/2009145)

Answer (score 2):

I think your expression should be `0 0 16 ? * * *`

There are many online cron evaluator you can use for both evaluating an expression or creating one.

Answer (score 2):

It should look like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 16 * * *")
    public void sendMsg() {
}
```